# How is velocity in this solution dependent on two lengths?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, constrained-dynamics

I found a solution for a problem I've been struggling with recently for a scissor lift table horizontal and vertical velocities. This research paper shows that both are dependent on $l$, $S$ and $h$. But the problem is l is a constant since it's the length of a steel bar that is supposed not to change, however the writer derived it first and applied derivative rule as if l was a variable. Does this mean this solution is wrong?

Here it is:

[image: suggested Solution of the problem]

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. The equation for h'(t) is wrong
the true equation would be $ 2h'(t)=(l^2-S^2(t))^{-1/2}*2S(t)S'(t)$
same in the equation vor S'(t) the h'(t) is missing and l'=0

Comment: I'm wondering how I can link S' (the horizontal velocity) with h' (vertical velocity)?

Comment: You have to know how or by what mechanism S changes position. It seems in some other picture this is shown?

Answer (score 0):

you have one degree on freedom which is $~S~$

from the constraint equation

$$ h^2+\left(\frac S2\right)^2=\left(\frac l2\right)^2\tag 1$$

you obtain

$$h=h(S)=\frac 12\sqrt{l^2-S^2}$$

thus
$$\dot h=\frac{\partial h}{\partial S}\,\dot S=
-\frac 12\,{\frac {S}{\sqrt {{l}^{2}-{S}^{2}}}}\,\dot S$$

with
$$\dot S=f(t)\quad ,S(t)=\int f(t)\,dt+S_0$$

and   $~S_0=\frac l2\,\cos(\theta)~$

you can obtain   the velocity $~\dot h(t)~$ and the position $~h(t)=\int \dot h\,dt$

**Notice**

$~S(t)\le l$